# How do I reference an id in a FragmentTransaction for a getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create nested fragments by using the `getChildFragmentManager` 
This is my code in the `SettingsFragment.java` code. I'm trying to replace it with the `GeneralPreferencesFragment` fragment.

**Code for SettingsFragment**

```
package com.example.android.memo.Fragments;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;

import com.example.android.memo.R;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener{


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private ViewGroup container;

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container);
        this.container = container;
        fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers);

        Preference generalPref = (Preference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference(getString(R.string.key_pref_general));

        generalPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

        if(preference.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.key_pref_general))) {
            GeneralPreferencesFragment generalPreferencesFragment = new GeneralPreferencesFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_settings_container, generalPreferencesFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        return true;
    }



}
```

However, it keeps popping up with this error because it cannot find the R.id.fragment_settings_container

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09005c (com.example.android.memo:id/fragment_main_container) for fragment GeneralPreferencesFragment{9017d3f #0 id=0x7f09005c}
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1422)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

I've looked at some other solutions and it says that the id I'm referencing must be a child of the layout I put in setContentView(). But because this is a Fragment, I'm using `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container);`
The id I'm referencing IS a child of the fragment_settings file so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
This is the **fragment_settings.xml** layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.memo.Fragments.SettingsFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_settings_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code for GeneralPreference**

```
package com.example.android.memo.Fragments;


import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.memo.R;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GeneralPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private void setPreferenceSummary(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();
        String key = preference.getKey();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            /* For list preferences, look up the correct display value in */
            /* the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values). */
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        /* Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file */
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
        PreferenceScreen prefScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        int count = prefScreen.getPreferenceCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Preference p = prefScreen.getPreference(i);
            if (!(p instanceof CheckBoxPreference)) {
                String value = sharedPreferences.getString(p.getKey(), "");
                setPreferenceSummary(p, value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        /* Unregister the preference change listener */
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        /* Register the preference change listener */
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Preference preference = findPreference(key);
        if (null != preference) {
            if (!(preference instanceof CheckBoxPreference)) {
                setPreferenceSummary(preference, sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post `GeneralPreferencesFragment` and `SettingsFragment` code as well.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code with GeneralPreferencesFragment and SettingsFragment

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** You are using a custom layout with `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, so you must use another way to make it work together.

**Solution:** You can following the following steps

Step 1: Go to `style.xml` then add these lines

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- Add this line -->
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/CustomPreferenceTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- Add this line -->
<style name="CustomPreferenceTheme" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="preferenceFragmentCompatStyle">@style/CustomPreferenceFragmentCompatStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Add this line -->
<style name="CustomPreferenceFragmentCompatStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceFragment.Material">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/fragment_settings</item>
</style>
```

Step 2: Change `fragment_settings` layout

**fragment_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/list_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 3: Modify `SettingsFragment` class

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.container = container;
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers);
        Preference generalPref = getPreferenceManager().findPreference(getString(R.string.key_pref_general));
        generalPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        if (preference.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.key_pref_general))) {
            GeneralPreferencesFragment generalPreferencesFragment = new GeneralPreferencesFragment();

            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.list_container, generalPreferencesFragment)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it works, however when I click on the General Preference, the GeneralPreferencesFragment opens but the xml is now on top of the SettingsFragment. Do you know how to fix this? The SettingsFragment still hasn't "disappeared" so to speak.

Comment: Also, do you know if when I click the back button on my android phone, if the screen will return to the headers screen?